# Can a heterogeneous binary relations be symmetric

Tags: relations, symmetry

This [Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_relation#Properties) lists the properties homogeneous relations may have.

I am wondering whether it makes sense or not to consider symmetry of non-homogeneous relations, or if necessarily :

$∀x∈X,∀y∈Y,(xRy⇔yRx)⇒X=Y$

If heterogeneous symmetric relations exist, could you please give a "real-world" example?

Comment: In the "old-fashioned" world, the relation "x is Married with y" is an heterogeneous symmetric relation between the sets of Males and Females.

Comment: Ok. Your answer makes me realise that my question was misleading. I have a computer scientist approach and I implicitly considered that X and Y represent different entity types such that there exist no set able to contain elements from two different types.